# "Unable to compute a percent/stacked axis containing non-numerical data" and "Not a number: NaN "

Tags: birt, silk-central

First I want to thank everyone for taking their time and helping me solve this issue.

Now I want to preface that I have never used Birt before. I am currently learning the very basics of Birt and its functionalities. This has been less than 24 hours.

I have a report in Silk Central that is showing me some unresolved issues. I dont know where to even begin with my diagnosing.

I have researched this issue online to no avail and I just wanted some opinion on what could be causing the issue or where I can look to solve the problem, etc.

I have a few possibilities -

1- My data source is broken - but the same datasource is being used for other reports that are functioning properly.

2- Maybe birt changed the XML mapping for one of the reports? So the data is not being produced accurately due to the change ?

3- Something is wrong with a driver?

Thank You all in advance

Kindly,

[image: What The Errors look like]

Comment: Have you changed the original SQL sentence or just the BIRT design? It seems like your filter includes some null values that are impossible to be graphically represented.

Comment: We did not change the SQL sentence nor BIRT design. The only difference is that BIRT updated something(versions - or a patch updated) then it broke.